# Jquery doesn't seem to locate DOM elements in Simple_form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm trying to use jQuery so that different parts or a form are revealed depending on which radio button is clicked. I used JSFiddle to get it working on a plain vanilla form first and all seemed fine however when I apply the same code logic to my rails app that uses the simple_form gem nothing seems to work.

See my code below

```
$("input[type=radio]").click(function(){
    if ($('input[name=usertype]:checked').val() == "User A") {
        $("#one").slideDown("fast");
        $("#two").slideUp("fast");
        $("#three").slideUp("fast");
        $("#four").slideUp("fast");
    }
    if ($('input[name=usertype]:checked').val() == "User B") {
        $("#two").slideDown("fast");
        $("#one").slideUp("fast");
        $("#three").slideUp("fast");
        $("#four").slideUp("fast");
    }
    if ($('input[name=usertype]:checked').val() == "User B") {
        $("#three").slideDown("fast");
        $("#two").slideUp("fast");
        $("#one").slideUp("fast");
        $("#four").slideUp("fast");
    }
    if ($('input[name=usertype]:checked').val() == "User B") {
        $("#four").slideDown("fast");
        $("#three").slideUp("fast");
        $("#two").slideUp("fast");
        $("#one").slideUp("fast");
    }
});

   <%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' }, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :email, placeholder: 'example@domain.com' %>
    <%= f.input :username %>
    <%= f.input :usertype, label: 'Which best describes you', :input_html => {:name => "usertype"}, :collection => ["User A", "User B", "User C", "User D"],
                as: :radio_buttons %>
    <ul id="one">
      <li><%= f.input :dob, label: 'Date of Birth', as: :date, start_year: Date.today.year - 90,
                  end_year: Date.today.year - 16,
                  order: [:day, :month, :year] %></li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="two">
      <li><%= f.input :launchedIn, label: 'Year club launched', as: :date, start_year: Date.today.year - 300,
                  end_year: Date.today.year, discard_day: true, discard_month: true, order: [:year] %></li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="three">
      <li><%= f.input :category, :collection => ["Football", "Golf", "Tennis", "Rugby"], prompt: 'Choose an Sport' %>
    </ul></li>
    <ul id="four">
      <li><%= f.input :bio, label: 'Tell us about you', hint: 'Maximum 300 characters' %></li>
    </ul>
    <%= f.input :password %>
    <%= f.input :password_confirmation %>
    <div><%= f.submit "Register", :class => 'btn btn-primary' %></div>
<% end %>
```

Have come with at least four version of JSFiddle that work, none however work on my rails app.

Would appreciate any help on this, as my stress ball can only take so much :-)

Many thanks

Kieran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you use Rails 3.2 or newer, ...try to:

1. check if JS generated by the app is correct (it contains your code) (source code of the html page)
2. did you by any chance run `rake assets:precompile` before applying this? Rails may be picking up that precomiled version of your application.js . If so try `rake assets:clean`
3. Make sure your jQuery is loaded before the file where you have your JS/CoffeeScript logic
4. Make sure you use `$(document).ready ->` in your JS/CoffeeScript file that is handling the logic

Comment: thanks re-running the rake assets pre-compile worked...relief

Comment: one more recommendation if you using versioning tool (e.g: git) like I do: while developing I always delete my `public/assets` dir with `rm -rf` (so than I don`t have to precompile each time I want to see changes) and than when I finish my changes I commit them and after that I checkout that dir `git co public/assets` to bring them back. Then run `assets precompile` and commit. If you're not using any versioning tool you really should look into it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your script is not under dom ready. Add your script within dom ready and it should work

```
jQuery(function($){
    $("input[type=radio]").click(function(){
        var val = $('input[name=usertype]:checked').val();
        if (val == "User A") {
            $("#one").slideDown("fast");
            $("#two").slideUp("fast");
            $("#three").slideUp("fast");
            $("#four").slideUp("fast");
        } else if (val == "User B") {
            $("#two").slideDown("fast");
            $("#one").slideUp("fast");
            $("#three").slideUp("fast");
            $("#four").slideUp("fast");
        } else if (val == "User B") {
            $("#three").slideDown("fast");
            $("#two").slideUp("fast");
            $("#one").slideUp("fast");
            $("#four").slideUp("fast");
        } else  if (val == "User B") {
            $("#four").slideDown("fast");
            $("#three").slideUp("fast");
            $("#two").slideUp("fast");
            $("#one").slideUp("fast");
        }
    });
});
```

You can also try something like

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var usertypes = $('input[name=usertype]'), uis = $('#one, #two, #three, #four'), valueMap = {
        "User A" : $('#one'),
        "User B" : $('#two'),
        "User C" : $('#three'),
        "User D" : $('#four')
    };
    $("input[type=radio]").click(function() {
        var val = usertypes.filter(':checked').val(), ui = valueMap[val];
        uis.not(ui).slideUp("fast");
        ui.slideDown("fast");
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rQpyP/)

Comment: reply below eventually solved my problem, thanks for taking the time to help though your feedback is very useful